# Setting auto height, depending on how many columns in is text area, but apparantly it adds empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhh8bLko/).

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var open = false;

var openSidebar = function () {
    $('.status-text').addClass('box-height');
    open = true;
}
var closeSidebar = function () {
    $('.status-text').height($("textarea")[0].scrollHeight).removeClass('box-height');
    open = false;
}

$('.status-text').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    openSidebar();

});

$(document).click(function (event) {
        closeSidebar();   
});
});
```

html

```
<textarea class="status-text" placeholder="test" style="width: 100%; ">
</textarea>
```

css

```
.box-height {
height:auto;
}
```

So, it kind of works. It adds height depending on how much text there is, but if I spam click on `$(document)`, it keeps adding height to textarea and you can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `document` `click`, why don't you call it on `focusout` of the text-area?

```
$('.status-text').focusout(function() { 
   // may be user an ID for the text area
   closeSidebar();
});
```

**Or try the following:**

JS

```
function auto_grow(element) {
    element.style.height = "5px";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

CSS

```
.status-text {
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="status-text" onkeyup="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: This seems to work better, tho if you write line 5 lines then focusout, make it 3 lines. It won't scale it down and instead add some additional height @_ @

Comment: That needs to be changed in the code itself. Even with current code it is not scaling down.

Answer (score 0):

For the shrink to work, set the textarea to 1 before calculating the height. That behavior of always increasing the height is caused by margins/padding. This works:

```
var closeSidebar = function () {
    $('.status-text').height(1);
    $('.status-text').height($("textarea")[0].scrollHeight - $('.status-text').outerHeight() + $('.status-text').height()).removeClass('box-height');
    open = false;
}
```